# Show dialog using getApplicationContext() - BadTokenException: Unable to add window

Tags: android, android-dialog

I know this might have discussed here before. But I am still confused what happens if I use `getApplicationContext()` to display a `Dialog`.

I have an application which uses `getApplicationContext()` to create  `AlertDialog.Builder`, and the **app crashes when the dialog is shown**. But if I use SomeActivity.this context it works fine.

*Note: This app was in play store for a while now and was working before, but not sure from which Android version this crashes.*

*Crash Stack Trace*

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:540)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> But I am still confused what happens if I use getApplicationContext() to display a Dialog.

You blow up.

> But if I use SomeActivity.this context it works fine.

Correct. A `Dialog` is owned by an `Activity`. [You cannot use an `Application`, `Service`, or other `Context` to show a `Dialog`](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/). Note, though, that you can use any `Context` to start a dialog-themed activity.

> but not sure from which Android version this crashes

Android 1.0, as far as I know.